# Geocode ips with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'd like to know an optimal way of implementing geocoding for the scrapy architecture. The aim is to collect coordinates of the visited ips while scrapy crawls, so not really to reprocess a table of ips for the geocoding.

Now, it is implemented as an ItemPipeline which uses several ip geolocation services. This is just working, as the overall crawler process is quite slow when using the geo pipeline. Maybe the crawler waits for the pipelines upon a number of requests queued in the pipeline?

Is there a way to **directly yield items that have been already geocoded** with scrapy?
Or in case, any idea for better results?

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @boardrider I edited the question, is think it meets now the requisites.